# I have pre installed windows 10 home and some weeks ago i got 2021-09 cumulative update but its not installing and showing error 0x800f081f

Tags: windows-10

I was trying to update this from a month but it always got this error every time it gpes to 100 % downloading and then 100% intsalling and then suddenly this error came with this--
there were some problem insatlling updates but we will try again latter blah blah and at the end error code is written which is (0x800f081f).

Please help i dont know what's wronggg.

Comment: get and run setupdiag - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag and post its output in your question

Comment: Provide the output of SetupDiag by performing an [edit] to your question.  SetupDiag can easily be found on the Microsoft website

Answer (score 1):

Informative Microsoft Article.

[Microsoft article on update issues](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-cumulative-update-error-0x800f081f/5e513035-a9f1-46e2-87af-58fa890dc123?auth=1)

**First try DISM and SFC repairs**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart

**Now cleanup Windows Update.**

> Again open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run the following
> commands.
>
> Net Stop bits
>
> Net Stop wuauserv
>
> Net Stop appidsvc
>
> Net Stop cryptsvc
>
> Ren %systemroot%SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.bak
>
> Ren %systemroot%system32catroot2 catroot2.bak
>
> Net Start bits
>
> Net Start wuauserv
>
> Net Start appidsvc
>
> Net Start cryptsvc

Restart and test.

**If the above fails to resolve update issues, then run Windows 10 Repair Install.**

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.

Use the first option:  Keep Everything and try that.

Windows 10 Repair Install has more aggressive options if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft defines
[Error code 0x800F081F](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/dotnet-framework-35-installation-error#error-code-0x800f081f)
as:

> This error code can occur when an alternative installation source is
> specified and one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The location that is specified by the path does not contain the files that are required to install the feature.
> - The user who tries to install the feature does not have at least READ access to the location and to the files.
> - The set of installation files is corrupted, incomplete, or invalid for the version of Windows that you are running.

This means that Windows Update has failed on your computer in a
strange way.

Below is some advice that may help to solve such problems:

- Run the Windows Update troubleshooter in:
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters >
  Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter*
- Run Microsoft's [Windows Update Troubleshooter for Windows 10](//support.microsoft.com/help/4027322)
- Reset Windows Update components by running these commands in an elevated
  Command Prompt:

  ```
  net stop wuauserv
  net stop cryptSvc
  net stop bits
  net stop msiserver
  Ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
  Ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
  net start msiserver
  net start wuauserv
  net start cryptSvc
  net start bits
  ```

  If all goes well, delete the `.old` folders (or return them if a problem
  arrives).
- Run the DISM tool in an elevated Command Prompt:

  ```
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
  ```
- Run the following in an elevated PowerShell shell:

  ```
  SC config trustedinstaller start=auto
  ```
- If nothing fixes the problem, use a heavy gun to install this update:
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](//tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)